# Serialization PhoneApplicationPage Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, xml-serialization

i hace a class named "Conexion" an i keep all the info of my app there, what i want its to save the object of the class to a file when the user presses the windows key, but the app crashes because it says the obect "delegado" has a problem reflecting his type. The type of this object is "PhoneApplicationPage" , it seems it cannot be serialized. The object keeps track of what page did the request.

so im requesting your help to see if theres a solution, that doesn make me redo the app, because i dont have time.

heres the code of the methods i use to save and load the data.

```
public void save() {

            IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.CreateFile(fileName);
            DateTime currTime = DateTime.Now;
            this.timeOff = currTime.ToString();
            XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
            xml.Serialize(stream, this);
            stream.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
    }

 public Conexion load() {

        IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        Conexion conn;

        if (storage.FileExists(fileName))
        {
            IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.OpenFile(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
            XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Conexion));
            conn = xml.Deserialize(stream) as Conexion;
            stream.Close();
            DateTime currTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime checkTime = DateTime.Parse(timeOff).AddMinutes(lapso);
            if (DateTime.Compare(checkTime, currTime) >= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("sesion valida");
            }
            else {
                conn.reseteaSingletonConexion();
            }
            stream.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            conn= new Conexion();
        }
        return conn;
    }
```

thanks in advance

Edit:

Well ignoring the object "delegado" stopped the app from crashing, but now , when i load the info , the object cannot be deserialized , it seems it marks 2 details in the same error:

```
There is an error in XML document (2, 2).
Conexion cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.
```

but the class does have a parameterless constructor.

any idea?

Comment: Could you provide the full Conexion class in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute against the objects that won't serialize (chances are you don't want to serialize the entire XAML page.

Place this attribute above a property in your `Conexion` class. Eg,

```
public class Conexion
{
    public string MyPropertyToSerialize { get;set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string MyPropertyToIgnore { get;set; }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks that stopped the app from crashing, but now i cant deserialize the object